# Stop Do you want to open facebook prompt when i called "logInWithReadPermissions" method in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using iOS SDK Facebook to login into my app. I have a Facebook login button (my own button, not the one provided) and it shows perfectly either the Facebook App (if is installed) or the Safari, and after that the facebook login page.

**ISSUE:** When i installed facebook and i click login with facebook button its asking "Do you want to open facebook" with open and cancel button. when i click open button the handler calling automatically.

```
 [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                //Checking for success login
                if (result) {
                    //user login successfully, get user information

                } else {
                    //user login failed
                    NSLog(@"facebook error %@", error);
                }
            }];
```

When i tried to get user inoformation in success method iam getting error.How can i stop asking prompt Do you want to open facebook when i click on  facebook button first time. And why success block is calling when i press open button.

Comment: Have you checked on different iOS versions ? What is the error message ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the login behavior to:

```
login.loginBehavior=FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
```

As default login behavior is via the application or native safari browser.
Changing it will prevent prompt from opening.